# show the selected cell to be highlighted in a collectionView, when same collectionView is used with 2 data sources

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have 2 buttons and 1 collectionView on a ViewController. On clicking one button the collectionView's data source changes and It is reloaded to change the options shown in the collectionView's cells, and on clicking the other button different options are shown.
I want to change the font of the text in the label(this label is present inside the cell) of the cell selected by the user.So, for that I did the following

```
var previouslySelectedCell: IndexPath? = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
var leftOutPreviouslySelectedCell: IndexPath?
```

In cellForItemAt:

```
cell?.frameNameLabel.font = UIFont.Book16    
if indexPath == previouslySelectedCell {
cell?.frameNameLabel.font = UIFont.Medium16
}
```

In didSelectItemAt:

```
    if previouslySelectedCell != nil {
      if let previousCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslySelectedCell!) as? FramePhotoCell {
   previousCell.frameNameLabel.font = UIFont.Book16
    } else {
     leftOutPreviouslySelectedCell = previouslySelectedCell
           }
  }
  let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! FramePhotoCell
  cell.frameNameLabel.font = UIFont.Medium16
  previouslySelectedCell = indexPath
```

In willDisplay:

```
if indexPath == leftOutPreviouslySelectedCell {
   (cell as! FramePhotoCell).frameNameLabel.font = UIFont.Book16
   leftOutPreviouslySelectedCell = nil
        }
```

Problem with this approach is that if I select a cell in one collectionView an then when I tap on a button which changes its dataSource and a new reloaded collectionView with new data appears; There too the previously selected cell (selected in previous version of collectionView) seems to be selected/highlighted, as that cell's IndexPath is there in the previously selected Cell.
I don't want to erase values of previously selected cell on switching to the other collectionView, as if a user selects one cell and then moves to the other version of collectionView, and then comes back to the previous version of collection view by tapping on the 2 buttons given, The previously selected cell should still be in the selected mode.
What should I do?

Comment: apply check on dataSource if its from Button1 then change font as your requirement else change font for 2nd one and also save state of which button is presed

Comment: I don't get the else part in `didSelectItemAt`. because `previouslySelectedCell` will be nil in that scope.

Comment: @hardikparmar collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslySelectedCell!) return a value only if the cell with that particular IndexPath is currently visible, otherwise it return nil

Comment: I get that. I was asking about the else part. setting `leftOutPreviouslySelectedCell = previouslySelectedCell` will set `leftOutPreviouslySelectedCell` to `nil`.

Comment: @hardikparmar
if user taps on a cell that is currently not visible (but is among those cells that have not been released from the memory [ if there are three complete cells visible on screen then 5 cells will be kept alive in memory. 
3 will be the visible ones, and the other 2 will be used as spare cells, one on the left and the other one on the right of those 3 visible cells. Those 5 cells keep getting recycled/reused. (I am considering the collectionView to be horizontal in this example.) the other 2 will not be visible as obviously, they are present out of the collectionView's width ] ),

Comment: continued...

then collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslySelectedCell!) will return nil. In this case when the user will scroll back to the previously selected cell, that cell will still be in the highlighted/selected mode. So, to handle that scenario and showing that previous cell as non-selected I am keeping that leftOutPreviouslySelectedCell variable. The cell whose value is stored in leftOutPreviouslySelectedCell will be brought back to non-selected/highlighted state when that cell will about to begetting displayed

Comment: If we don't consider this scenario then the cells will return to there normal state only when they'll be fpormed again by cellForItemAt

Comment: My dearest friend, what I am trying to tell you is `leftOutPreviouslySelectedCell` will always be `nil` unless you are setting it somewhere else in your code other than `didSelectItemAt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an array as `arrSelectedIndex`

In `OnBtnClick`

```
if index is not in array{
 1. add index in array
 2. reload your data
}
else if index is in array{
 1. remove index in array
 2. reload your data
}
```

In `cellForRow`

```
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row

1. check cuurent indexPath is in the `arrSelectedIndex` or not.
2. if step1 true{
  show your hightlighted data
}
else{
  show default data
}
```

hope this helps you.